# How to stop form from submitting using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the code I have. I want to prevent the form from submitting if the message i receive from the php side is 0 (an error occured). If the message received is 1 I want to submit the form.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        register();


    });

});


    function register(){

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"submit.php",
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg){

                if(parseInt(msg)==1){
                    window.location=msg;
                }
                else if(parseInt(msg)==0){  
                    $('#error_out').html(msg);
                }


            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#form').submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();

           //do whatever you want

});
```

Answer (score 5):

after `register();` include `return false;`

Comment: I only want to prevent submission when i receive a msg = '1'

Comment: Then you would need to make the ajax synchronous. add `async: false` to the ajax parameters and move the `return false;` to the success function (under `window.location=msg`).

Comment: +1. fastest answer I have ever seen.. just 38 seconds for answering this question.

Comment: It still does not not prevent me using no async and adding the return false;

Comment: ah sorry. Change `register();` to `return register();`

Comment: Basically, to cancel a form submission, you need to return false from the callback function.

Comment: So, you have `async: false`, `return false;` in the success callback under `window.location=msg`, and `return register();`?

Comment: Yes. BTW, I meant to prevent submission when msg is 0 not 1.

Comment: Wait a second...didn't you say you wanted the form NOT to submit if the msg is 0? Then we have the `return false` in the wrong place...it would need to be moved under `$('#error_out').html(msg);`

Comment: @Rodaine let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1330/discussion-between-user461316-and-rodaine)

Answer (score 0):

after `register();` include `return false;` if it doesn't work then rename `register();` to `register(e);` and then include `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand ,Try use this:

if(parseInt(msg)==0){  
                   $('#submit').attr('disabled','true');
                }